# C# Threads and this.Invalidate()

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, graphics

I'm developing a **Windows Mobile** app (**Compact Framework 2.0 SP1**) and this code it's generating me an error:

```
        public Image Imagen
        {
            get
            {
                return imagen;
            }
            set
            {
                imagen = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

The code is called from a new thread. I've tried to solve using **InvokeRequired:

```
        public Image Imagen
        {
            get
            {
                return imagen;
            }
            set
            {
                imagen = value;
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    this.Invoke(this.Invalidate);
                else
                    this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

But the line **this.Invoke(this.Invalidate);** doesn't compile. How can I solve the problem? The first error is that you can interact with controls created on another thread.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Long winded version of why this is necessary.  Instead of taking a specific Delegate type as a parameter, the Invoke method takes the type System.Delegate.  This type does not providing typing for a strongly typed signature.  It's the base delegate class and instead provides a common mechanism for invoking all delegates.

Unfortunately when passing a method name as a Delegate source in C# it must be passed to a specific delegate type.  Otherwise C# doesn't know what type of delegate to create under the hood and unlike VB it won't generate anonymous delegate types.  This is why you need a specific delegate type like MethodInvoker in order to call the function.

**EDIT** Manually defined MethodInvoker since it doesn't exist in the Compact Framework

```
public delegate void MethodInvoker();

public Image Imagen
{
    get { get return imagen; }
    set {
        imagen = value;
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Invalidate));
        else
            this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: This Winform is for windows mobile so I use Compact Framework that it hasn't got methodinvoker.

Answer (score 8):

Invalidate doesn't need an invoke.

The invalidate only includes a paint message to be processed by the main thread with the rest of the pending messages. But the paint is not done when you call to invalidate and the control is not changed by this thread, so you don't need to use an invoke for it.

If you need to ensure that the control is refreshed, maybe the invalidate is not enough and you need to call to the update too.

Answer (score 0):

The function Invoke expects an delegate, so you can use the built in Action delegate:

```
public Image Imagen
{
    get
    {
        return imagen;
    }
    set
    {
        imagen = value;
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(new Action(this.Invalidate));
        else
            this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: @VansFannel, System.Action (no-generics) was added in .Net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

My solution for **Compact Framework 2.0 SP1** is this:

```
...

delegate void InvocadorMetodos();

...

        public Image Imagen
        {
            get
            {
                return imagen;
            }
            set
            {
                imagen = value;
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    InvocadorMetodos invalida = Invalidar;
                    this.Invoke(invalida);
                }
                else
                    this.Invalidar();

            }
        }
```

Thank you!